# Bootstrap Table row-clicked event

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using a `<b-table>` component in a Vue project and I need to define a function to be triggered when a row is clicked. I heard that there is a `@row-clicked` property in `b-table` so I tried to use it and I can put simple functions inside of it, I mean I can get console prints etc but nothing more complicated...

I want two functions to be executed when a row is clicked. The functions are now bound to a button inside of every row, but I dont want use it like this, I just need to click the related row to make them work. Here is the current version of the `b-table` component;

```
      <b-table
        :items="displayByType"
        :fields="displayColumn"
        responsive="sm"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :current-page="currentPage"
        :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
        :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
        :filter="filter"
        :filter-included-fields="filterOn"
        @filtered="onFiltered"
        hover
        @row-clicked="test"
      >
```

And here is the two functions that I want to be triggered when a row is clicked...

```
toggleRightBar(){
  document.body.classList.toggle("right-bar-enabled");
}

changeRightBarContent(row){
  this.$store.dispatch("rightbar/changeRightBarInfo", tableData[row]);
},
```

There is a JavaScript folder that I export column names and row data. I also a have Rightbar, when a row is clicked, I want to enable the rightbar so that the user can see detailed information about that specific row.

At last, here is the button that I use to make these two functions work;

```
        <template #cell(detail)="row">
          <button @click="toggleRightBar(); changeRightBarContent(row.index);" class="btn btn-outline-primary toggle-right">
            <i class="bx bx-detail toggle-right"></i>
          </button>
        </template>
```

Basically, I dont want to use this button, instead, I want to click the row itself. Every row's rightbar information will be uniqe, my function does that. I just dont know how to use these 2 functions inside `@row-clicked`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I just dont know how to use these 2 functions inside @row-clicked`, Have you tried the same way you do in your `@click` event.

Comment: I need to revise the functions because @row-clicked is waiting for a "row" information to execute the method. So I need to pass the row inside the toggleRightBar function but I don't know how to that since the function only toggles a CSS class. I can put two functions like @row-clicked="test1(); test2()", but the functions need to be revised and they have to have "row" I guess....

Comment: `toggleRightBar` doesn't expect any arguments? Did you mean `changeRightBarContent`? Also, is there any reason why you aren't calling `toggleRightBar` from inside `changeRightBarContent`?

Comment: changeRightBarContent does expect an argument, toggleRightBar simply not working. No console error, nothing. It's working in every button in rows but it's not working when I put it inside @row-clicked.

Comment: You said: `So I need to pass the row inside the toggleRightBar function`, which is why i asked, because `toggleRightBar` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: I know. That is the awkward part. I can't think of any other possibility. It simply toggles a CSS class but it doesnt work in @row-clicked. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

The `row-clicked` event will pass 3 parameters to your function.
The first being the item specific to the row that was clicked. The second will be the index of the row, and the third is a native click event.

This means you can use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) keyword to get the `index` and pass it to your function.

`@row-clicked="toggleRightBar(); changeRightBarContent(arguments[1])"`.

Alternatively you can create a third method which will call the other two.

```html
<b-table @row-clicked="onRowClicked" />

{
  onRowClicked(item, index, event) {
    this.toggleRightBar();
    this.changeRightBarContent(index);
  }
}
```

You can read more about the `@row-clicked` event on the docs component reference section.
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-events

Comment: Doesn't this onRowClicked function expect argument for item and event?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: When I use onRowClicked to call the other two functions, it gives me error that says event and item is defined but never used. Therefore I am able to use these two methods inside row-clicked as you explained above.

Comment: If your linter doesn't want unused arguments, you can remove them. However, you should only remove the ones *after* the one you use. So in this case you'd only want to remove `event`